# счётчик по клику плюс и минус

Tags: javascript, html

написал скрипт но он не работает, буду признателен если подскажите где ошибся, при нажатии `counter-elem__plus` число увеличиваеться на 1 при `counter-elem__minus` отбавляем 1

```js
  var splashVal = document.querySelector(".splash-input").value;
        var count = 0;
        document.querySelector(".counter-elem__plus").onclick = function() {
            count += parseFloat(splashVal + 1);
            splashVal = count;
        }
        document.querySelector(".counter-elem__minus").onclick = function() {
            if (count > 1) {
            count += parseFloat(splashVal - 1);
            splashVal = count;
          } 
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="counter-elem__input splash-input" value="5">
    <div class="counter-elem__arrow counter-elem__plus"></div>
    <div class="counter-elem__arrow counter-elem__minus"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы не присваиваете новое значение инпуту. Видимо, Вы хотите сделать это таким образом `splashVal = count;`. Но тут `count` - это просто переменная. Она никоим образом не ссылается на сам инпут. Вы просто увеличили ее и все. Может так?

```js
var splashInput = document.querySelector(".splash-input");
var splashVal = parseFloat(splashInput.value);
document.querySelector(".counter-elem__plus").onclick = function() {
  splashInput.value = ++splashVal;
}
document.querySelector(".counter-elem__minus").onclick = function() {
  if (splashVal > 1) {
    splashInput.value = --splashVal;
  } 
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="counter-elem__input splash-input" value="5">
<div class="counter-elem__arrow counter-elem__plus">Up</div>
<div class="counter-elem__arrow counter-elem__minus">Down</div>
```

**P.S.**
Точно ниже единицы не должно опускаться? Может имели ввиду ниже нуля?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector(".splash-input").value` возвращает строку. Вам нужно привести её к типу `number`, чтобы операция `+` выполнялась не как конкатенация строк, а как сложение чисел.

```
var splashVal = parseInt(document.querySelector(".splash-input").value, 10);
```